# OpenCV - Display percentage instead of line

Tags: opencv, percentage

This is a application that can recognize emotions of happy/sad/anger/neutral/disgust/surprise.

The line will increase based on the current emotion that it recognize.

The link below is image of my current work , but I want to display percentage instead of line, but I not sure how.

http://postimg.org/image/j6hhe4dy7/

Anyone can help me with this would really appreciate.

Here is the part of code :

```
if(showTrackerGui) {
    CvScalar expColor = cvScalar(0,254,0);
    cvFlip(img, NULL, 1);

    int start=12, step=15, current;
    current = start;
    for(int i = 0; i < N_EXPRESSIONS; i++, current+=step) 
    {
        //this line display the emotion.
        cvPutText(img, EXP_NAMES[i], cvPoint(5, current), &font, expColor);
    }

    expressions = get_class_weights(features);

    current = start - 3; 
    for(int i = 0; i < N_EXPRESSIONS; i++, current+=step) 
    {
        //this is the line which display the green line but I want to display percentage.
        cvLine(img, cvPoint(80, current), cvPoint((int)(80+expressions.at<double>(0,i)*50), current), expColor, 2);
    }

    current += step + step;
    if(showFeatures == 1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N_FEATURES; i++)
        {
            current += step;
            char buf[4];
            sprintf(buf, "%.2f", features.at<float>(0,i));
            cvPutText(img, buf, cvPoint(5, current), &font, expColor);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can look at the line that prints the emotion titles which shows you exactly the method you want to call:

```
cvPutText(img, EXP_NAMES[i], cvPoint(5, current), &font, expColor);
```

And the line you want to change is:

```
cvLine(img, cvPoint(80, current), cvPoint((int)(80+expressions.at<double>(0,i)*50), current), expColor, 2);
```

So try replacing the line with `cvLine()` with the following:

```
// Assuming expressions.at<double>(0, i) returns a value between 0.0 and
// 1.0, convert it to 0.0 to 100.0.
double percentage = expressions.at<double>(0, i) * 100.0;

// Format the string buffer to hold "{percentage} %" (e.g., "50 %").
char buf[6]; // 3 bytes for the percentage, 1 for the space, 1 for the "%", 1 for the null byte.
sprintf(buf, "%3.f %%", percentage);

// Display percentage.
cvPutText(img, buf, cvPoint(80, current), &font, expColor);
```